# How can I detect a file on a USB connected to a Raspberry Pi running Windows 10 IoT Core? (C# UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to dynamically enumerate the drive letters of USBs as they are connected to my Raspberry Pi running Windows 10 IoT Core.

It is my understanding that I can use `Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceWatcher` or `DeviceWatcherTrigger` to do this. Once a USB is detected I also want to be able to see if it is empty or, if it isn't, scan for whether it contains a file in a specified directory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems correct, just subscribe to the `Add` and `Update` events.

Comment: Use KnownFolders.RemovableDevices() to access the storage device because StorageDevice.FromId() seems not work on Windows IoT.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceWatcher to enumerate the portable storage devices on-the-fly, just listen to the Added/Removed/Updated event of DeviceWatcher shall be good enough.

A good tip is if you want to listen to the event in the background(aka, when the foreground app is suspended, you need to handle the Added/Removed/Updated event in a separate windows runtime component, and register the background watcher with Add/Remove/Update event triggers.

Refer to the [DeviceEnumerationAndPairing](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing/cs) demo project on github for code samples.

Comment: So using that demo project I have gotten to the point where I can detect when a USB is added or removed to/from the Raspberry Pi but from there I do not know how to find the Drive Letter of that storage device. Any tips?

Comment: @maxblaster5000, sorry for the delay, maybe you can refer to this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112787/using-deviceid-from-windows-devices-enumeration-to-find-the-drive-letter-of-a-re