# Using DeviceID from Windows.Devices.Enumeration to find the Drive Letter of a Removable Drive (USB) in C# Windows 10 IoT Core?

Tags: c#, uwp, detection, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to scan a USB drive that is inserted into a Raspberry Pi running Windows 10 IoT Core for a specific file in a specific folder. I am currently able to detect when a USB drive is added or removed from the device using Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceWatcher and can find the DeviceId using that as well. I did this using the [DeviceEnumerationAndPairing](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing/cs) demo project. I am aware that StorageDevice.FromId() would work for this usually but it seems to not agree with Windows 10 IoT Core. I have also tried using KnownFolders.RemovableDevices to loop through all the devices whenever a device is added but that always immediately crashes the application. I want to be able to use the DeviceId to find the drive letter of the USB device and then check if the drive is empty or not and if not, navigate in that device to the directory and file I expect to be there.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following code lines in the `handlerAdded()` in scenario2 of the [DeviceEnumerationAndPairing](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing/cs) demo project.

```
var removableDevices = KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;

// Get all driver letters
var folders = await removableDevices.GetFoldersAsync();

if (folders.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (StorageFolder folder in folders)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(folder.Name);

        // Check the driver letter is empty or not.
        var items = folder.GetItemsAsync();
        if (items == null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("There are no files and folders.");
        }
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, you need declare the `Capability` of file type you want to access, pictures, for example, you can add the following line in the Package.appxmanifest.

This works for me. Hope it is helpful for you.

```
<uap:Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
```

Comment: That code did work to enumerate the usb drives when added, however it doesn't say when a usb is empty. I have checked to make sure the usb is actually empty, and it is. This has helped a lot though. I will keep poking around in the code to see what the issue is and get back to you.

Comment: I changed the line

Comment: I changed `if (items== null)` to `if (items.GetResults().Count == 0)` and that seemed to work

Comment: It should be an `await` in the `GetItemsAsync` call: the full line should be `var items = await folder.GetItemsAsync();`. Now the `items` will be of type `IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem>`.